# Wireshark decoding URL from M – SEARCH * HTTP/1.1

Tags: wireshark

I am new to Wireshark and when I am running Wireshark it shows me the source address as the IP address but the destination address is 239.255.255.250 and at the info tab it shows M – SEARCH * HTTP/1.1. My question is that if there is a way to decode that info and find which machine is using which URL. Thank you

Comment: You are looking at Multicast SSDP packets which are used to discover uPnP devices on the local network. It's not web traffic.